# Cakephp i18n extracts all but one template file

Tags: php, cakephp, localization, internationalization, cakephp-2.0

I have a site with dynamic content, with only some button labels and headers in the template files. In the View folder I have multiple *.ctp files, for example profile.ctp and index.ctp. My problem is that when I run the cake console's i18n extract function, then the translateable strings from the controller.php and profile.ctp are picked up, but index.ctp is ignored.

I tried running
`cake i18n extract --files .\View\ControllerName\index.ctp --ignore-model-validation --output .\Locale\ --paths .  --overwrite yes --extract-core no --merge no`

This however gives no results, and no *.pom files are created, unlike when I run it without the `--files` argument. In that case just the strings from the view are missing from the *.pom file.

The interesting thing is that in the console output it shows that the index.ctp is parsed, but still no results are given.

```
Output Directory: C:\Dev\app\Locale\
---------------------------------------------------------------
Processing C:\Dev\app\View\ControllerName\index.ctp...
Processing C:\Dev\app\View\ControllerName\profile.ctp...

Done.
```

So, my question is - does anyone have any idea on why it is so? Is there a setting to disable certain templates, or is it the default behavior to ignore index.ctp files? Or am I just doing something really wrong?

Thank you!

**Edit:** Solved. Don't use shorthand PHP tags just in case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after lots of headwracking I decided to try something out. I copied profile.ctp content into index.ctp, then it worked. After that I just started stripping down the index.ctp until it worked. Turns out that if I used shorthand PHP tags (`<? ?>`) then for some reason the translation strings detection didn't work, but when I used full tags (`<?php ?>`) then everything was fine. Figures :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a stupid remark, but does your index.ctp actually contain translatable strings (i.e. strings wrapped into `__("sentence to translate");` function) ?

Comment: Yea, they're there alright.. One for each button text :)